# Can I use a php embed inside a javascript for my mobile website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a javascript that displays a message on a mobile website in a drop-down bubble. I also have a lightweight cms that generates simple html files that I use to update portions of the website. I use php embed to pull the text from the CMS into the mobile web page.

I would like to use the cms to update the text that is inside the drop-down bubble, but it seems to break the javascript when I do. Is there a way to accomplish my intended goal?

Here is the javascript snippet, minus the script brackets:

```
var addToHomeConfig = {
message2: "REPLACE THIS TEXT WITH .HTML FILE FROM CMS",
message:"Featuring LIVE MUSIC on Thursdays. See our EVENTS menu for schedule.",
textcolor: "#ffffff",
bgcolor: "#69532f",
returningVisitor: true,
animationIn: "drop",
animationOut: "fade",
startDelay:5000,
lifespan:10000,
expire:240,touchIcon:true};
```

This is a sample of my embed code and the resulting HTML page. This would replace the "REPLACE THIS TEXT..." part of the snippet above.

`<?php include("admin/data/blocks/Special-of-the-Day.html"); ?>`

The content of this html file is:

`<p>Come down and enjoy Andrea Wirth on the patio between 7pm and 9pm.</p>`

Comment: I think you're getting your server/client languages and spheres of influence mixed up. Unless you're generating the javascript file on the fly via php you will not be able to use php inside of the javascript file.

Comment: Do you have any line breaks inside that HTML file?

Comment: Also, it that in an external js file?

Comment: No breaks in the html. It is exactly what you see, nothing else. Just the line wrapped by p tags.

The code above is embedded in the same html document. There are two js files that are external.

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

and...

{loadjsfile("http://mobilereadynow.com/instapop/src/add2home.js");}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use server side script in client side

Comment: but there is a option to do that via `AJAX`

Comment: There are no line breaks in the HTML file. It is just a line of text with a <p> tag.

I am new to javascript and php, so please pardon my utter naivety. Since the php is processed before the page is displayed, is there a way to assign the result of the php include to a variable in the javascript? 

What I am trying to do is provide a way to remotely update the text content of that bubble.

Comment: How do I accomplish my goal with AJAX?